Coq can you enter a tactic context inside of a `Fixpoint` definition?
I can use an opaque term created by a tactic in a Fixpoint definition.
(* opaque wrong factorial *)
Lemma opaque_func : nat -> nat.
Proof. auto. Qed.

Fixpoint frobnicate (x : nat) :=
  match x with
  | O => opaque_func 0
  | S x => x + opaque_func x
  end
.

We can demonstrate that opaque_func is really opaque by trying to show what it sends 0 to.
Example opaque_func_zero : opaque_func 0 = 0.
Proof.
  unfold opaque_func.

produces the cool error:
Error: opaque_func is opaque.

However, the opacity of opaque_func is not an obstacle to using it inside a Fixpoint definition.
That got me wondering whether it is possible to "inline" the tactic used to create opaque_func into the definition of frobnicate.
Strawman syntax below:
Fixpoint frobnicate (x : nat) :=
  match x with
  | O => { auto } 0
  | S x => x + { auto } x
  end
.

Is there an actual way to enter a tactic context from inside a Fixpoint definition like this in Coq?

In complement of the approach using tactics in terms by means of the ltac: keyword, a more flexible approach (in particular, which gives access to a full blown interactive proof mode) is given by the Obligation mechanism of Program and Equations. In short, this mechanism lets you leave holes in your code, which are then left to be filled interactively.
Here is an example, using Program:
Require Import Program.

(* By default, Program tries to automatically solves the holes,
  using a custom tactic, which can be printed by using: *)
Show Obligation Tactic.

(* This tactic can be (locally) overriden with the following command: *)
#[local] Obligation Tactic := idtac.

Program Fixpoint frobnicate (x : nat) :=
  match x with
  | O => _ 0
  | S x => x + _ x
  end.
Next Obligation.
  auto.
Qed.
Next Obligation.
  auto.
Qed.


Fixpoint frobnicate (x : nat) {struct x} : nat :=
  match x with
  | O => ltac:(intros y; eauto) 0
  | S x => x + ltac:(intros y; eauto) frobnicate x
  end.

Is this an answer that you want?
The response of Print frobnicate. is:
frobnicate = fix frobnicate (x : nat) : nat := match x with
| 0 => (fun y : nat => y) 0
| S x0 => x0 + (fun y : nat -> nat => y) frobnicate x0
end
: nat -> nat

Arguments frobnicate x%nat_scope

